# How to display express errors in ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, ejs

I am validating emails users enter using "emailCheck" and a piece of code I found on another question, this is the code in my app:

```
app.post("/blog", (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;

    emailCheck(email).then(() => {
        const newSubscriber = {name: name, email: email};
        Subscriber.create(newSubscriber).then(() => {
            res.redirect("/blog")
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.json({serverErrorEmailExistence: "This email adress is already in use!"})
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
        res.json({serverErrorEmailExistence: "This Email doesn't exist!"})
    })
})
```

This works as it is, but the errors are shown on a new blank page. I would like to show the error under the form that I have. Form is in included as a partial in my app.

Here is the form html:

```
<section id="emailSub">
    <div id="emailContainer">
        <h1>Subscribe to my Newsletter</h1>
        <p>You will get weekly emails when a post is published.</p>
        <form action="blog" method="POST" id="emailForm" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name: " name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email: " name="email" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Subscribe!</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="thankYouMsg">
        <h1>Thank you for subscribing!</h1>
        <p><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></p>
    </div>

    <button id="exitForm"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
</section>
```

I include this on the blog main page with:

```
<%-include("partials/subscribe") %>
```

And here is my subscriber model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const SubscriberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Subscriber", SubscriberSchema)
```

How can I show that error in the form?
The div with the ID thankYouMSg is shown after a successful form submit, usually it is hidden with Css.

I tried searching for this and I found a lot of answers but I either don't know how to include them in my code or I don't understand enough to search for the right answer (might be both). To be honest, I just included the emailcheck code in my app the best I know how. I don't really understand what .catch(error) is delivering.

Thank you

Following the answer I tried:

```
.catch(() => {
            res.render("/blog", {errorMessage: "This email adress is already in use!"});
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
        res.render("/blog", {errorMessage: "This Email doesn't exist!"})
    })
```

But, I get the "cannot look up view /blog in views". I tried the same with 
res.redirect and it just loads without anything happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that in case of an error, you catch this error and return a `json`-response which the browser cannot render directly in `html`.

What you can do instead, is re-send your subscribe page and pass the caught error message to that page, which you can render there. Something like this should help you get started:

in your app.js

```
...
.catch(() => {
    res.render("your-subscribe-template.ejs", {
        errorMessage: 'This Email doesn\'t exist!'
    });
});
...
```

in your template.ejs:

```
...
<% if (typeof errorMessage !== "undefined") { %>
    <p>Form could not be submitted due to the following error:</p>
    <p><%= errorMessage %></p>
<% } %>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I can't get it right. I try what you said. and if I use res.render("/blog", {...}) I get an error "failed to look up view /blog". If I try the same but with res.redirect, it just loads for a long time

Comment: I moved subscribe to its own page rather than a partial and it works. Thank you again